# Why does the -fno-objc-exceptions flag change the size of the compiled .o file, even when there's no exception-related code in the .m?

Tags: objective-c, exception, clang

I recompiled a file that doesn't use `@try`, `@catch`, or `@finally`, and it became 20% smaller. Why would this be? Why wouldn't Xcode use -fno-objc-exceptions for any file that doesn't use those keywords?

Comment: This is an educated guess at the moment, but: just because your code doesn't have any `@try`/`@catch`/`@finally` doesn't mean that it doesn't call out to somewhere that _can_ throw an exception. And when an exception is thrown, the stack needs to be unwound, which requires storing additional information in the object file. `-fno-objc-exceptions` tells the compiler that you absolutely don't want to include that information because you're sure it can't throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You're telling the compiler to omit stack unwinding information that it would otherwise use to help propagate exceptions cleanly through code.

---

For background, it's helpful to know what exceptions are and what happens when they are thrown (and caught). Since there are plenty of [detailed resources online](https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/series/exception-handling-in-c/) which cover the topic, I'll briefly summarize here:

- When an exception is thrown (whether in C++ or Objective-C), the exception and some associated information are carried up through the call stack to a place where they can be handled. This is done through a process called [stack unwinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Unwinding) — in essence, it's like an early return from a function which captures some information about where in the function the return happened
- To produce that information (usually presented in the form of a [backtrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)), the compiler needs to embed information about how to unwind through the stack at arbitrary locations (since exceptions can be thrown deep in a code base and travel up to just about anywhere)
- In C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++, both clang and GCC use the C++ exception machinery to generate unwinding information and propagate exceptions up the stack (as well as handle the exception in C++ and Objective-C)
- The compiler turns on `-fexceptions` by default because it has no way of telling where an exception *might* be thrown through your code. Since a function in one `.m` file can call another in a different `.m` file (which *can* throw an exception), the only safe thing for the compiler to do in the general case is always enable exceptions and unwinding information
- This unwinding information, then takes up space in your executable implicitly. If you want to turn off the unwinding information and tell the compiler "I'm sure that no exception will be thrown through any of the code here", then you can pass `-fno-exceptions` to turn off exceptions globally for the file, or `-fno-objc-exceptions` for turning off exceptions in Objective-C code. (Note that if an exception is *still* thrown through the code, you'll likely get a pretty garbage backtrace, if anything at all)

GCC has some more information about the [`-fexceptions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fexceptions) flag which enables exceptions by default, and clang has [similar information](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-fexceptions), though in less detail.

Comment: When you say "get a pretty garbage backtrace", are you saying that consumers wouldn't be able to catch anything that's trying to propagate through an object that was compiled with `-fno-exceptions`? What about for crash reporting, when an uncaught (e.g. because no one wanted to catch it or it couldn't propagate) exception occurred, would the crash get properly symbolicated?

Comment: @meisel Without unwinding information, any middle layers in the backtrace are essentially opaque to the exception — it can still propagate through that code, but it won't gather any information about it. Crash reporting shouldn't be affected on Darwin platforms, though, as backtraces are produced differently (interrogating the stack pointer and propagating back through that).

Comment: One place that might be affected in a meaningful way is in code compiled with `-fobjc-arc-exceptions`, which causes ARC to [do the right memory management in the face of exceptions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions). (This is off by default for Objective-C code, but on by default for Objective-C++ code.)

Comment: What information would it need to gather on a Darwin platform then as it propagates? Is there any tradeoff on this platform, or can I just always disable exceptions for files that don't use `@try`, `@catch`, etc.?